# USB hosting with UsbSerialForAndroid won't receive serial data

Tags: usb

I'm using an OTG cable to allow my 'moto-e6 play' (Android version 9) to be a USB host to an AdaFruit Trinket M0. Off the shelf, the Trinket repeatedly sends a serial text string as soon as it powers up, and I've verified it does that when I connect Putty to it from my Windows PC. On my phone I have code using a Xamarin port of UsbSerialForAndroid. The code successfully finds the device and opens the port, but I see no serial data coming from the device. Specifically, the UsbDeviceConnection.RequestWait within the UsbSerialPort.Read method blocks forever. If I replace the RequestWait with a 1-second Sleep, there's nothing in the buffer. I've also tried all the different protocols that UsbSerialForAndroid supports (CdcAcmSerialDriver, etc.) to no avail. Also, the phone registers the Trinket as a keyboard, but I assume that still allows other code to access it, as well. Does anyone know what the problem is or what I might try to get serial working? Here's the simplified (Xamarin) code without error checking:

```
usbManager = GetSystemService(Context.UsbService) as UsbManager;

var usbDevice = usbManager.DeviceList.ToList()[0].Value;

if (!usbManager.HasPermission(usbDevice))
   usbManager.RequestPermission(usbDevice, null);

var table = UsbSerialProber.DefaultProbeTable;

var type = typeof(Hoho.Android.UsbSerial.Driver.CdcAcmSerialDriver);
               
table.AddProduct(0x239A, 0x801F, type);

var prober = new UsbSerialProber(table);

var drivers = prober.FindAllDrivers(usbManager);

var driver = drivers[0];

UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.OpenDevice(driver.GetDevice());

var ports = driver.GetPorts(); // Most devices have just one port (port 0)

var port = ports[0]; // Most devices have just one port (port 0)

port.Open(connection);

// The following serial params are the same as I successfully used with Putty on Windows

port.SetParameters(9600, 8, Hoho.Android.UsbSerial.Driver.StopBits.One, UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

var bytes = new byte[32];

var len = port.Read(bytes, 32); // <-- this hangs at the RequestWait call
```

Comment: The Baud rate for a USB device typically is not really used, but I've seen devices that still check that it' s a common value

Comment: Could your Trinket be expecting flow control? According to the [original library's FAQ](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/wiki/FAQ#feature-matrix), it looks like there's no automatic flow control, so you might want to try manually setting DTR enabled.